# VoiceXML to Asterisk Dialplan parser

Tags: parsing, asterisk, voicexml

Is there any existing parsers to parse VoiceXML file to Asterisk Dialplan? I have searched on google, but could not find anything. So I am guessing, is it actually possible, or maybe these technologies not intended to be converted to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but they are inconvertible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Vxi*](http://www.i6net.com/products/vxi/)?
It provide to append parsing VoiceXML process for Asterisk.

If you will install Vxi*, you can writting configuration file as follows.

```
[incoming]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,Wait(3)
exten => s,n,Vxml(http://vxml.i6net.com/index.vxml)
exten => s,n,Hangup
```

Comment: Thanks, Bladean. But, I realized that they are inconvertible.